# Нужно ли знать другие языки программирования кроме Java для Андроид-разработчика?

Tags: android

Нужно ли знать другие языки программирования кроме Java для Андроид-разработчика?
И хватит ли уроков от Sturtdroid для изучения андроид разработки?

Comment: нет, не нужно...

Comment: Другие языки, кроме Java, для полноценной разработки под Android знать не нужно. Уроков startandroid со всей определенностью недостаточно, они вообще плохо подходят для обучения разработке, больше, как типовые примеры решения определенных задач - это для тех, кто уже что то понимает. Если вы действительно хотите научится разрабатывать - читайте книжки. По Core Java (если не знаете язык), например Б.Эккель "Философия Java", по Android API - Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование  для профессионалов" это даст вам в разы больше полезных знаний, чем разрозненные уроки в инете.

Comment: startAndroid же самый непонятный ресурс..много гораздо более внятно объясняющих уроков

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, почему некоторые так негативно среагировали на нормальный бытовой вопрос. Да нужно. Чем больше вы знаете - тем лучше. Кроме java вам следует учить Kotlin, т.к. это новый официальный язык разработки под android (с 2018). Кроме того, разработка под android сопровождается большим количеством верстки экранов в xml редакторе, поэтому если вы хотите делать приложения, которые адаптируются под экраны пользователей, навык верстки тоже нужен. Android предлагает множество готовых решение в своей библиотеке matireal design, которая постоянно обновляется. Ее вам нужно знать очень хорошо, почти как Отче Наш))

В меньше степени вам нужно разбираться в:

- proguard - используется для скрытия ваших кодов при публикации приложения.
- gradle - если хотите создавать адаптивные сборки, то простым подключением библиотек обойтись не получиться. Придется подтянуть знания в gradle.

В целом, вам нужно держать нос по ветру, следить, и пробовать тенденции. В противном случае, вы будете делать лишнюю работу, либо отстанете. Удачи, учитесь!

Comment: Потому что "Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях." Он нарушает правила ruSO

Comment: Вряд ли этот вопрос может что-то порождать. Здесь мнение едино. Любой, кто разрабатывает под android скажется вам тоже самое, мб добавит что. Это всем известно, кхалиси.

Comment: Согласен, больше вопросов порождает ваш ответ) давайте начнем с логики. Вы говорите "всем", мне - неизвестно. Это уже не "все", а "некоторые". То есть у вас уже в рассуждениях логическая ошибка. Я разрабатываю под андроид и не говорю вам тоже самое. Вы додумываете за автора вопросы, которые он не изложил, один из основных который: "для чего нужно?" Работать программистом, зарабатывать деньги или писать программы для себя? Вопрос не отвечает требованиям правил "изложить суть проблемы". Я вот, например, удивляюсь зачем его плюсуют)

Comment: Виной всему проф-деформация) Вы смотрите на начинающих слишком профессионально, не понимая, что их вопросы просты, и ответов они джут простых.

Comment: Да, может быть) хотя и на самом деле считаю, что на начальном этапе ничего не нужно знать кроме "startandroid". Опять же, если не искать работу, а заниматься разработкой для себя, ничего лишнего знать не нужно вообще. Оформил бы как ответ, но уже отписался в комментах) есть два мнения, пусть автор выберет сам)